# Async returns null even after using AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Below is my Async class

```
public class GetBitMapFromURL   extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>
{
    byte[] tempByte;
    private Bitmap bmap;
@Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String stringUrl = params[0];
        //bmap = null;
        try 
        {
            URL url = new URL(stringUrl);
            InputStream is = (InputStream) url.getContent();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
            int bytesRead;
            ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            while ((bytesRead = is.read(buffer)) != -1) 
            {
                output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            tempByte = output.toByteArray();
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        return "Success";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
    {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Bitmap tempBitMap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(tempByte, 0, tempByte.length);
        //Log.d("Bitmap bmap value on PostExecute", "bmap="+bmap);
        setBitMap(tempBitMap);
        //imageView.setImageBitmap(bImg);
    }
    void setBitMap(Bitmap bitMapSet)
    {
        this.bmap  = bitMapSet;
        //Log.d("Bitmap bmap value", "bmap="+bmap);
    }
    Bitmap returnBitmap()
    {
        //Log.d("Bitmap bmap value", "bmap="+bmap);
        return bmap;
    }

}
```

In spite of doing the following in my activity, the returnBitMap() returns null.

```
GetBitMapFromURL gbmap1 = new GetBitMapFromURL();       //Obtain medium bitmap
    gbmap1.execute(applicationImageMediumURL);
    if(gbmap1.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED)
    {
        applicationMediumBitMap = gbmap1.returnBitmap();
     }
```

Suggest me as to where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Have you debugged into it? *Is* the status FINISHED?

Comment: Do you have this in a loop or something? That if statement will only get executed once... If you walk through with a debugger, you should know the line where the null gets assigned.

Comment: How do you know that the content of the `if` check for `FINISHED` is actually being executed?  Since `execute` is asynchronous and will be performed in a separate thread, I would be very surprised if your entire `doInBackground` code has run between your call to `execute` and the following `if` test.

Comment: You can't be sure it is finished and that data will be available. This is all at runtime, AsyncTask will take (even little) time. That is why I propose you the callback method :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do that, use the AsyncTask.onPostExecute() method to update the UI like

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
{
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    applicationMediumBitMap  = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(tempByte, 0, tempByte.length);
    //Log.d("Bitmap bmap value on PostExecute", "bmap="+bmap);

   // call any method on the activity to continue the process..
   otherStuff();
}
```

and remove the code

```
  if(gbmap1.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED)
   {
        applicationMediumBitMap = gbmap1.returnBitmap();
    }

   // other stuff code
```

in the Activity onCreate() (I guess). Put any following code to this on its own Activity method and call it within onPostExecute().

```
private void otherStuff() {
   // other stuff code
}
```